# pointing a skipped item and the error field in a chunk in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

### Scenario 1

The skip listener interface is as below:

```
public interface SkipListener<T,S> extends StepListener {
 void onSkipInRead(Throwable t);
 void onSkipInProcess(T item, Throwable t);
 void onSkipInWrite(S item, Throwable t);
}
```

This interface is best used to log the skipped item and the error.

Is is possible to get the number of the skipped item in the input. For e.g. if the 10th item in the input is getting skipped, I should be able to log "Item number 10 was skipped!" through above listener.

I need this since I have input as a file where the rows are not having any identifying key. So just by logging out the item, it would not be possible to pin point the item itself in the file.

What if instead of file, the input is a database table ? Is it possible to get the position number of the skipped item there as well ?

### Scenario 2

My bean has three properties one, two and three (all strings) where the input is read from a file through appropriate row mapper and then a database table gets loaded with the data after some processing.

Below is a code block from processor:

```
if(two.charAt(4) == '_')
   { // do some processing }
```

Clearly if field two is coming empty from the file above block will throw "string index out of bound exception" and will get skipped.

So, inside skip listener, what I want is the information about the column which threw error.

Here since field named two gave error, the information I would like to log in skip listener would be like "Property one threw error "string index out of bound exception" in line number 10" or if possible, even more specific "property one is empty in line number 10" which makes more sense to business who does not know java jargons.

Hope I made my doubts clear.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: "is it possible" questions are somehow vague - the usual answer would be yes, can you get a bit more concrete?

Comment: @MichaelLange: Please see the question again. I have tried to explain the doubts. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Scenario 1**

to get line number for skipped item from reading a **file** you can:

- for onSkipInRead - implement own/wrap the reader to act on exception
- onSkipInProcess - implement own linemapper which writes line number to item or writes current line number in step context
- onsKipInWrite - same as for onSkipInProcess

to get line number for skipped item from reading a **table** you can:

- for onSkipInRead - implement own/wrap the reader to act on exception, but i'm not sure if it's possible to the get the line number here, might only be the current chunk-start-number
- onSkipInProcess - implement own rowmapper which writes row number to item or writes current row number in step context
- onsKipInWrite - same as for onSkipInProcess

**Scenario 2**

see scenario 1 and add a try/catch block inside your processor, so you throw your own exception e.g. with information on property position, or alter the step context in a similar way